# Create a unique group id over a window in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, uniqueidentifier

I have a dataframe where I want to add unique ids for groups in the dataset

```
 id |   zip   | name | quot
 1  |  30000  | abc  |  10
 2  |  30000  | abc  |  10
 3  |  40000  | kal  |  10
 4  |  50000  | res  |  20
 5  |  50000  | res  |  20
 6  |  60000  | dei  |  20
 7  |  60000  | dei  |  20
```

And I want to generate a common `UUID` for each zip in the dataset so that it looks e.g. like

```
 id |   zip   | name |  groupguid
 1  |  30000  | abc  |  FA4E4089-C3ED-41C4-B88C-000C6673A692
 2  |  30000  | abc  |  FA4E4089-C3ED-41C4-B88C-000C6673A692
 3  |  40000  | kal  |  860BDE48-9B4A-450E-BD68-001B90E8F977
 4  |  50000  | res  |  EAE3AFB7-412D-437E-8A15-001BE52373A3
 5  |  50000  | res  |  EAE3AFB7-412D-437E-8A15-001BE52373A3
 6  |  60000  | dei  |  AA8F1518-7F35-4E76-A550-002CF9C455AB
 7  |  60000  | dei  |  AA8F1518-7F35-4E76-A550-002CF9C455AB
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

One way using Spark SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

spark.sql("""  
    SELECT * 
    ,      first(uuid()) over (partition by zip) as groupguid 
    FROM df_table 
""").show
```

Or just use selectExpr:

```
df.selectExpr(
    "*"
  , "first(uuid()) over (partition by zip) as groupguid"
).show
```

Comment: or with DataFrame API : `df.withColumn("groupguid",first(callUDF("UUID")).over(Window.partitionBy($"zip")))`

Answer (score 0):

Now this works but when I run

```
var df = raw.selectExpr(
  "*",
  "first(uuid()) over (partition by zip) as groupguid",
  "first(uuid()) over (partition by name) as groupname"
  )
)
```

then

```
display(df)
```

gives me a groupguid and groupname that is not identical to if I run

```
display(df.select("groupguid") 
display(df.select("groupname")
```

How can I ensure that groupguid and groupname does not change?